# How do I get dev tools to open up inside of chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Every time I open dev tools in google chrome, it opens in a new window. Is there a way for it to open up inside of my chrome window? I'm using a mac if that makes a difference

Thank you!
Ky

Answer (score 1):

On the top right corner of the developer tools window there is a kebab (three dots arranged vertically) menu where you can select how you want it to open. You have set to a separate window (which is the first option form the left), pick one of the other options (which are dock positions):

[image: Menu]

Answer (score 0):

Left click on the page you want the dev-tools to open up on and click on the inspect option.

Answer (score 0):

In 3 dots in the corner in the top right you can change the view mode:

[image: like this]